# How to redirect standard output when a vim command opens a url at cursor in browser?

Tags: vim

I'm using a vim plugin and when I want to look up a function under the cursor in the online api docs, I type '\da'

Here's the vimscipt code for the keymapping:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <LocalLeader>dda :silent call <SID>OpenURL('http://api.drush.ws/api/function/')<CR><C-L>
```

When the command is run, it writes the standard output from the shell into the current vim buffer, so the phrase:
"Created new window in existing browser session." will be written into the current buffer.

Also here's the openurl function:

```
  function s:OpenURL(base)
     let open = b:Drupal_info.OPEN_COMMAND
     if open == ''
       return
     endif
     let func =  shellescape(expand('<cword>'))
     if a:base == 'api.d.o'
       if strlen(b:Drupal_info.CORE)
         execute '!' . open . ' http://api.drupal.org/api/search/' .
         \ b:Drupal_info.CORE . '/' . func
       else
         execute '!' . open . ' http://api.drupal.org/' . func
       endif
     else
       execute '!' . open . ' ' . a:base . func
     endif
   endfun
```

How do I fix this/redirect stdout?

(I'm using ubuntu/gnome.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see anything that will put command output into the current buffer. But if you don’t want to observe command output at all, you can do one of two things:

1. Put `silent` in front of each `!` (note: you must have the space after `silent`) and add `redraw!` command just before `endfunction`.
2. Replace every `execute '!'.<...>` with `call system(<...>)` (in this case having newline in arguments is much likely to cause bugs).

Comment: call system(<...>) fixed the issue. Thanks so much!